# Will PHP lock a file if it's being read by multiple scripts?

Tags: php, locking

I have a text file with only one line of text that is being read from two scripts.

Will I be able to write to that file while it's being read or will I run into locking issues? Should move the one line into a database, or will it be fine in the text file?

Comment: A database is a lot less work/maintenance than a text file; *believe me, I've been there*.

Comment: Btw, file locking is only required when writing to files, not when reading. But do use a database; you'll thank me in the long run ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Reading from multiple PHP pages does not require file locking.

Comment: That's not what the question is about. It's about reading a `.txt` file from multiple pages; not reading `.php` files.

Comment: OP: *"I have a text file with only one line of text that is being read from two pages."* - what am I not grasping?

Comment: *Groan* - ok. My bad. Long day and tired eyes.

Comment: Haha, yes, I know the feeling. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are only reading from the file and not writing to the file you will be fine if you set php to read the file in "read only" mode.

From the documentation listed below:

```
<?php
     $handle = fopen("c:\\folder\\resource.txt", "r");
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php